Altium keepout clearance violation
i have a connector footprint which has a keepout of the top layer, the problem is as soon as i connect the track a clearance violation appeared.
If i change the keepout restrictions in the footprint  to allow tracks that will no longer be a keepout.
Could anyone suggest how to solve it? If the problem can be solved in the footprint itself that will be the best scenario, other than that how can i set a custom query for it in the rules (i don't know too much about queries in altium)
You can see the pictures attached for more details.


Thank you.

Change the keepout shape to not overlap the pads.

You may need to modify the footprint.

The Photon:
If i do that so any pad put there will not trigger a violation
